# Using XSLT to parse non-wrapped json

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

In all the xslt examples I've seen for converting json to xml, the json is always wrapped in xml tags before processing using the json-to-xml() function. I'm curious if it's possible to do the conversion without wrapping the json. I've been playing with [this xslt fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22json-to-xml%28.%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22contents%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%230000FF%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22green%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%2300FF00%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%23FF0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON) to no avail, but if I wrap it in `<data></data>` and then change the input type to xml it works. Does anyone have any guidance on how to get the xslt in the fiddle to work with bare json?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the Fiddle invokes Saxon, but I suspect that when you select the input type as JSON, it actually parses the JSON and supplies the resulting structure of maps and arrays as the initial context item. Unfortunately the json-to-xml() function expects unparsed lexical JSON as input, so the only way I can make this work is to re-serialize the JSON, like this:

```
<xsl:template match=".">
      <xsl:copy-of select="serialize(., 
         map{'method':'json'}) => json-to-xml()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the `match="."` rather than `match="/"`, because "/" will only match the root of an XML document, whereas "." will match anything.

If you weren't constrained by the way the Fiddle is implemented, you could supply the JSON content to the stylesheet as a string, or as the URI of a file, which you could read using `unparsed-text()`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that works great! I've been using the fiddle to experiment with json-to-xml, but I will be using SaxonJs in a node application. Am I understanding that when I use it in code I can just use `<xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text())"/>` ? When I try that I get an error "Wrong argument arity 0 for function unparsed-text()"

Comment: @ssdev, do you start your SaxonJS XSLT stylesheet with the named template `xsl:initial-template` and pass the JSON file name in as a parameter? Then use the file name parameter for the argument to `unparsed-text($fileName)`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Here is a code sandbox where I am attempting to parse the json in Saxon. I've commented some things out as different things keep failing. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sharp-lalande-tmqz68?file=%2Findex.ts%3A50%2C31
I tried following https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/transform/parameters for passing parameters, but feel like I'm misunderstanding the docs.

Comment: @ssdev, I am not sure there is currently a working way to have your JavaScript or Typescript code compile XSLT on the fly to SEF, as you seem to be trying, let's see whether Michael Kay or someone else form Saxonica thinks that is supported with SaxonJS 2, I think you might need to wait for SaxonJS 3 to be have that supported. The others issues are just that you pass in a JavaScript or Typescript object as a map but for reasons I don't understand try to use `unparsed-text` on that. Any anyway, your JavaScript array (the `content` value) inside your objects gets converted to an XDM sequence.

Comment: I am not sure there is a good way to pass such an object with an array to XSLT or XPath as parameter to preserve the array on the XSLT/XPath side as an XDM array, I only see examples where the array is wrapped into an array e.g. `contents : [[...]]`. But then of course you have the XDM map and need Mike's suggestion `$mapVar => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json' }) => json-to-xml()` and also start with i.e. `<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">`. Don't provide any source object other than e.g. `stylesheetLocation: "convert.xsl.sef" (where you got the `.sef` with xslt3).

Comment: Start with `<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">`, if you don't have a source node to process.

Comment: The attempt I got to output some object converted to XML is at https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gracious-feynman-4gwypq?file=%2Findex.ts%3A76%2C6. Quite sure that you don't want to have to wrap an array in an array but I am not sure there is another approach, using the JSON serialization and have XSLT/XPath use `json-to-xml($jsonString)` might be safer.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. That codesandbox was me just trying to work out ideas, I wasn't sure how unparsed-text was used. I appreciate you sending me a link to a working solution. I'll explore it and keep diving through the saxon docs. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle, if you choose input type JSON, indeed parses the JSON from the input editor with `parse-json` into an XPath 3.1 XDM map or array. So I would say it works with raw JSON, in the representation XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 uses. However, your XSLT has to take that into account, `match="/"` tries to match an XML document node, it will never match an XDM map or array representing JSON; you can use `match="."` to match any item, so [the identity "raw" JSON to JSON would be at this fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22contents%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%230000FF%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22green%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%2300FF00%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%23FF0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON), doing e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A ["raw" JSON to JSON transformation, incrementing the id is at this fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22map%3Aput%28.%2C%20%27contents%27%2C%20array%20%7B%20%3Fcontents%3F*%20%21%20map%3Aput%28.%2C%20%27id%27%2C%20%3Fid%20%2B%201%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22contents%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%230000FF%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22green%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%2300FF00%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%23FF0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON), doing e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match=".">
      <xsl:sequence select="map:put(., 'contents', array { ?contents?* ! map:put(., 'id', ?id + 1) })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for intention to apply `json-to-xml`, Michael has already explained that, as the function doesn't work with an XDM representation of JSON, like a map or array, but rather on a string input of the JSON, you would need to serialize as JSON and then apply `json-to-xml`, as shown in that accepted answer.

Neither my fiddle nor SaxonJS has any option to use a text file's string content directly as the context item, the BaseX fiddle, however can do that, so [there](https://bxfiddle.cloud.basexgmbh.de/?share=%28%27query%21%27json-to-xml%7B.C%21%27%2878Gnts8%20%3A%20%5BD16blue50000FFA26green500FF00A36red5FF00008I%297%5DH%29%27%7Emode%21%27XQuery%20%7BBaseXCType%21%27text%27%29*EE4I*858Jhexcode98%236Jcolor987H*8%5C%279%5C%21%20A8I%29%2CDC%7D%27%7EGxtDI%284id9E%20%20GconteH%5CnI7*J%2C4%01JIHGEDCA987654*_), with the right context type text, you can use `json-to-xml(.)`.

I have also updated the XSLT 3, SaxonJS 2 powered fiddle to allow plain text input, so if you use JSON input data but treat it as plain text, as in [this fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22json-to-xml%28.%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22contents%22%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%230000FF%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22green%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%2300FF00%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22hexcode%22%3A%20%22%23FF0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&input-type=TEXT), you can indeed use `json-to-xml(.)`.